# Set array1 = array2 in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have one initialized array `arr1` and one declared array `arr2`. How can I simply set `arr2 = arr1`?

```
void setup() {

  int arr1[5][2]= { {1,1},
                    {1,2}};

  int arr2[5][2];


  arr2 = arr1; // Throws error "invalid array assignment"
}
```

Is it possible to do that in C++? And if so, how? I'd like to prevent using loops for this.

Comment: *Is it possible to do that in C++* -- Regular, dumb arrays, regardless of the number of dimensions, are not assignable using `=` in C++.

Comment: You could use `std::copy`, but it's much less of a kludge to just use `std::array` instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can’t assign C arrays in this way, but you can assign `std::array`s and `std::vector`s:

```
auto a1 = std::vector<std::vector<int>>{{1, 1}, {1, 2}};
auto a2 = a1;
```

(`std::array`s work the same way but are more verbose, since you need to specify the number of dimensions as template arguments.)

This example performs copy construction rather than assignment, which is what you’ll want to use 99% of the time. Assignment also works, the same way.

It is worth noting that this is *not* a multi-dimensional array — it’s a *nested array*. C++ has no native type for multi-dimensional arrays, but various libraries (mostly for numerical computation) provide them, for instance [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) and [xtensor](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). These may seem superficially similar to nested arrays, but both their API and their implementation differ in crucial ways. Notably, they are laid out *contiguously* in memory, which nested vectors aren’t (though nested `std::array`s *are*).

Comment: Nitpicking, but `auto a2 = a1;` is not assignment but copy construction.

Comment: @dfri While that’s correct, it’s almost certainly what OP actually wants.

Comment: I fully agree, my (very nitpicking) comment was solely intended to address the terminology (not the content) of the answer, as I see many C++ novices mixing up assignment and copy construction.

Answer (score 6):

Arrays can't be assigned, but they can be *copied* (using e.g. [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) or [`std::memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy)).

A possible better solution is to use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead, as then you *can* use plain and simple assignment:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 5> arr1 = {{
    { 1, 1 },
    { 1, 2 }
}};

std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 5> arr2;
arr2 = arr1;
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution is to use C++, not C.

```
  std::array<std::array<int,5>,5> arr1 =
     { {1,1},
       {1,2} };

  auto arr2 = arr1;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use std::array:

```
void setup() {

  std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2> arr1= { {1,1},
                    {1,2}};

  std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 2> arr2;


  arr2 = arr1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `std::array` instead of raw C arrays: it's a POD and can be copied (copy assignment; overwrites every element of the array with the corresponding element of another array) in a natural manner:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using ArrayType = std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 3>;
    ArrayType arr{{
        {1, 2},
        {3, 4},
        {5, 6}
    }};

    ArrayType arr_copy;

    // Copy arr into arr_copy.
    arr_copy = arr;

    // Mutation of original array will not affect the
    // elements of the copy.
    arr[0][0] = 42;
    std::cout << arr_copy[0][0]; // 1 (original value)

    return 0;
}
```